# Places AutoComplete Api tracking prevention blocked access to storage

Tags: javascript, api, maps

I am trying to test a Google Places autocomplete API that uses a google maps API as well but the API call is being blocked. I keep getting the following error and I don't know why.

tracking prevention blocked access to storage for https://maps.google.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/52/9/util.js.

The API KEY I used is not for my account it belongs to another person. It works on his machine without the error.

Please can anyone help me know why this is happening ?